# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore upgrade get similar operation id

Tags: swashbuckle

current application using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 1.1.0
this year target to perform framework to .net core 3.1 or .net 5
at same time upgrade Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to 6.1.5
find out does not have operationid any more and need custom it
with reference https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#assign-explicit-operationids

my concern is how to get back the same operationid (same as version 1.1.0)

below is sammple of my swagger json outcome from version 1.1.0

**api route with parameter (difficult)**

```
{
    "/api/Games/{id}": {
        "post": {
            "tags": ["Games"],
            "operationId": "ApiGamesByIdPost"
        }
    }
}
```

**normal sample**

```
{
    "/api/Games/Sequence": {
    "get": {
        "operationId": "ApiGamesSequenceGet"
}
```

i would resolved below one using

```
options.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
{
          return apiDesc.RelativePath.Replace("/", "") + apiDesc.HttpMethod;
});
```

but it only aby resolved for normal sample but not api route with parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can put any string into the `Name` property in the HTTP method attribute

```
[HttpPost("someobject/add", Name = "ApiGamesSequenceGet")]
```

Swashbuckle will take that value as `operationId` for your action method.